# Google Apps Script: Saving Gmail Attachment to Google Drive and replacement of characters in the saved attachment file name

Tags: google-apps-script

how can I swap characters from the filename that is saved in GDrive? e.g. "/" to "-"

I am using this great script -> https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive/blob/master/Code.gs &
https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive/blob/master/Config.gs

It works really well.
But i would like to exchange letters for the attachment filename that is saved.

I use this script from https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive:

Code.gs

```
// Gmail2GDrive
// https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive

/**
 * Returns the label with the given name or creates it if not existing.
 */
function getOrCreateLabel(labelName) {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);
  if (label == null) {
    label = GmailApp.createLabel(labelName);
  }
  return label;
}

/**
 * Recursive function to create and return a complete folder path.
 */
function getOrCreateSubFolder(baseFolder,folderArray) {
  if (folderArray.length == 0) {
    return baseFolder;
  }
  var nextFolderName = folderArray.shift();
  var nextFolder = null;
  var folders = baseFolder.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    if (folder.getName() == nextFolderName) {
      nextFolder = folder;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (nextFolder == null) {
    // Folder does not exist - create it.
    nextFolder = baseFolder.createFolder(nextFolderName);
  }
  return getOrCreateSubFolder(nextFolder,folderArray);
}

/**
 * Returns the GDrive folder with the given path.
 */
function getFolderByPath(path) {
  var parts = path.split("/");

  if (parts[0] == '') parts.shift(); // Did path start at root, '/'?

  var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var result = folder.getFoldersByName(parts[i]);
    if (result.hasNext()) {
      folder = result.next();
    } else {
      throw new Error( "folder not found." );
    }
  }
  return folder;
}

/**
 * Returns the GDrive folder with the given name or creates it if not existing.
 */
function getOrCreateFolder(folderName) {
  var folder;
  try {
    folder = getFolderByPath(folderName);
  } catch(e) {
    var folderArray = folderName.split("/");
    folder = getOrCreateSubFolder(DriveApp.getRootFolder(), folderArray);
  }
  return folder;
}

/**
 * Processes a message
 */
function processMessage(message, rule, config) {
  Logger.log("INFO:       Processing message: "+message.getSubject() + " (" + message.getId() + ")");
  var messageDate = message.getDate();
  var attachments = message.getAttachments();
  for (var attIdx=0; attIdx<attachments.length; attIdx++) {
    var attachment = attachments[attIdx];
    Logger.log("INFO:         Processing attachment: "+attachment.getName());
    var match = true;
    if (rule.filenameFromRegexp) {
    var re = new RegExp(rule.filenameFromRegexp);
      match = (attachment.getName()).match(re);
    }
    if (!match) {
      Logger.log("INFO:           Rejecting file '" + attachment.getName() + " not matching" + rule.filenameFromRegexp);
      continue;
    }
    try {
      var folder = getOrCreateFolder(Utilities.formatDate(messageDate, config.timezone, rule.folder));
      var file = folder.createFile(attachment);
      var filename = file.getName();
      if (rule.filenameFrom && rule.filenameTo && rule.filenameFrom == file.getName()) {
        filename = Utilities.formatDate(messageDate, config.timezone, rule.filenameTo.replace('%s',message.getSubject()));
        Logger.log("INFO:           Renaming matched file '" + file.getName() + "' -> '" + filename + "'");
        file.setName(filename);
      }
      else if (rule.filenameTo) {
        filename = Utilities.formatDate(messageDate, config.timezone, rule.filenameTo.replace('%s',message.getSubject()));
        Logger.log("INFO:           Renaming '" + file.getName() + "' -> '" + filename + "'");
        file.setName(filename);
      }
      file.setDescription("Mail title: " + message.getSubject() + "\nMail date: " + message.getDate() + "\nMail link: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/" + message.getId());
      Utilities.sleep(config.sleepTime);
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Generate HTML code for one message of a thread.
 */
function processThreadToHtml(thread) {
  Logger.log("INFO:   Generating HTML code of thread '" + thread.getFirstMessageSubject() + "'");
  var messages = thread.getMessages();
  var html = "";
  for (var msgIdx=0; msgIdx<messages.length; msgIdx++) {
    var message = messages[msgIdx];
    html += "From: " + message.getFrom() + "<br />\n";
    html += "To: " + message.getTo() + "<br />\n";
    html += "Date: " + message.getDate() + "<br />\n";
    html += "Subject: " + message.getSubject() + "<br />\n";
    html += "<hr />\n";
    html += message.getBody() + "\n";
    html += "<hr />\n";
  }
  return html;
}

/**
* Generate a PDF document for the whole thread using HTML from .
 */
function processThreadToPdf(thread, rule) {
  Logger.log("INFO: Saving PDF copy of thread '" + thread.getFirstMessageSubject() + "'");
  var folder = getOrCreateFolder(rule.folder);
  var html = processThreadToHtml(thread);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, 'text/html');
  var pdf = folder.createFile(blob.getAs('application/pdf')).setName(thread.getFirstMessageSubject() + ".pdf");
  return pdf;
}

/**
 * Main function that processes Gmail attachments and stores them in Google Drive.
 * Use this as trigger function for periodic execution.
 */
function Gmail2GDrive() {
  if (!GmailApp) return; // Skip script execution if GMail is currently not available (yes this happens from time to time and triggers spam emails!)
  var config = getGmail2GDriveConfig();
  var label = getOrCreateLabel(config.processedLabel);
  var end, start, runTime;
  start = new Date(); // Start timer

  Logger.log("INFO: Starting mail attachment processing.");
  if (config.globalFilter===undefined) {
    config.globalFilter = "has:attachment -in:trash -in:drafts -in:spam";
  }

  // Iterate over all rules:
  for (var ruleIdx=0; ruleIdx<config.rules.length; ruleIdx++) {
    var rule = config.rules[ruleIdx];
    var gSearchExp  = config.globalFilter + " " + rule.filter + " -label:" + config.processedLabel;
    if (config.newerThan != "") {
      gSearchExp += " newer_than:" + config.newerThan;
    }
    var doArchive = rule.archive == true;
    var doPDF = rule.saveThreadPDF == true;

    // Process all threads matching the search expression:
    var threads = GmailApp.search(gSearchExp);
    Logger.log("INFO:   Processing rule: "+gSearchExp);
    for (var threadIdx=0; threadIdx<threads.length; threadIdx++) {
      var thread = threads[threadIdx];
      end = new Date();
      runTime = (end.getTime() - start.getTime())/1000;
      Logger.log("INFO:     Processing thread: "+thread.getFirstMessageSubject() + " (runtime: " + runTime + "s/" + config.maxRuntime + "s)");
      if (runTime >= config.maxRuntime) {
        Logger.log("WARNING: Self terminating script after " + runTime + "s");
        return;
      }

      // Process all messages of a thread:
      var messages = thread.getMessages();
      for (var msgIdx=0; msgIdx<messages.length; msgIdx++) {
        var message = messages[msgIdx];
        processMessage(message, rule, config);
      }
      if (doPDF) { // Generate a PDF document of a thread:
        processThreadToPdf(thread, rule);
      }

      // Mark a thread as processed:
      thread.addLabel(label);

      if (doArchive) { // Archive a thread if required
        Logger.log("INFO:     Archiving thread '" + thread.getFirstMessageSubject() + "' ...");
        thread.moveToArchive();
      }
    }
  }
  end = new Date(); // Stop timer
  runTime = (end.getTime() - start.getTime())/1000;
  Logger.log("INFO: Finished mail attachment processing after " + runTime + "s");
}
```

and for Config.gs:

```
/**
 * Configuration for Gmail2GDrive
 * See https://github.com/ahochsteger/gmail2gdrive/blob/master/README.md for a config reference
 */
function getGmail2GDriveConfig() {
  return {
    // Global filter
    "globalFilter": "-in:trash -in:drafts -in:spam",
    // Gmail label for processed threads (will be created, if not existing):
    "processedLabel": "to-gdrive/processed",
    // Sleep time in milli seconds between processed messages:
    "sleepTime": 100,
    // Maximum script runtime in seconds (google scripts will be killed after 5 minutes):
    "maxRuntime": 280,
    // Only process message newer than (leave empty for no restriction; use d, m and y for day, month and year):
    "newerThan": "1m",
    // Timezone for date/time operations:
    "timezone": "GMT",
    // Processing rules:
    "rules": [
      { // Store all attachments sent to my.name+scans@gmail.com to the folder "Scans"
        "filter": "has:attachment to:my.name+scans@gmail.com",
        "folder": "'Scans'-yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
      { // Store all attachments from example1@example.com to the folder "Examples/example1"
        "filter": "has:attachment from:example1@example.com",
        "folder": "'Examples/example1'"
      },
      { // Store all pdf attachments from example2@example.com to the folder "Examples/example2"
        "filter": "has:attachment from:example2@example.com",
        "folder": "'Examples/example2'",
        "filenameFromRegexp": ".*\.pdf$"
      },
      { // Store all attachments from example3a@example.com OR from:example3b@example.com
        // to the folder "Examples/example3ab" while renaming all attachments to the pattern
        // defined in 'filenameTo' and archive the thread.
        "filter": "has:attachment (from:example3a@example.com OR from:example3b@example.com)",
        "folder": "'Examples/example3ab'",
        "filenameTo": "'file-'yyyy-MM-dd-'%s.txt'",
        "archive": true
      },
      {
        // Store threads marked with label "PDF" in the folder "PDF Emails" als PDF document.
        "filter": "label:PDF",
        "saveThreadPDF": true,
        "folder": "PDF Emails"
      },
      { // Store all attachments named "file.txt" from example4@example.com to the
        // folder "Examples/example4" and rename the attachment to the pattern
        // defined in 'filenameTo' and archive the thread.
        "filter": "has:attachment from:example4@example.com",
        "folder": "'Examples/example4'",
        "filenameFrom": "file.txt",
        "filenameTo": "'file-'yyyy-MM-dd-'%s.txt'"
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

I use this part to save the PDF attachments

```
  { // Store all pdf attachments from example2@example.com to the folder "Examples/example2"
    "filter": "has:attachment from:example2@example.com",
    "folder": "'Examples/example2'",
    "filenameFromRegexp": ".*\.pdf$"
  },
```

However, the character "/" is often used in the filename of the attachment. e.g. "Konto/postbox3226.pdf"
How can I replace this with e.g. "-" to "Konto-postbox3226.pdf"
Does that work with the replace command? If so, how do I have to use this?

many thanks for your help

Comment: Could you narrow down what you want users to review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have taken a deeper look at the code and I found how to change the name of the file that it is stored in Google Drive.
In `code.gs` line 92:

```
    try {
      var folder = getOrCreateFolder(Utilities.formatDate(messageDate, config.timezone, rule.folder));
      // NEW CODE
      var new_filename = attachment.getName()
      new_filename = new_filename.replace('/','-')
      attachment.setName(new_filename)
      var file = folder.createFile(attachment);
```

**Reference**

- [File.getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getname)
- [File.setName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setnamename)
- [Folder.createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfileblob)

Let me know if that finally works

Comment: great, it works.

There is only one small problem left.
Almost all characters can be replaced, except for these characters /
Is there anything special about these "/" signs?

Thank you for your help